# CKFinder Thumbnail Display Template

Tags: templates, plugins, ckfinder

I need to modify the display template for thumbnails when in the "view by thumbnails" mode.
I need to display the date/time that is currently being displayed in UTC, in the local time.

I have read through the plugin documentation, but I am unable to suss out where that would actually happen.  Also I can't find any plugins, that would address this issue.

Comment: What CKFinder version and connector type do you use?

Comment: Using Version 3.4.2 with the .NET Connector

Comment: Please try using the latest version then. This issue has been fixed in v3.4.5.